# queryPurchases is empty but the user is under the right account and when trying to buy it says they already own the item

Tags: android, android-billing

I have a user for whom `queryPurchases` returns an empty list. I got them to fix it temporarily by clearing Play Store data but then it broke again. I got logs from the user and the list is empty, all the codes look right.

I am using `com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.2`.

When I ask them to try to buy again it tells them that they already own the item.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: does it work if device is restarted?

Comment: Typically that doesn't fix it. It is a rare issue. Resetting Play Store data will sometimes fix it but then it might break again a bit later.